# Constructor doesn't update class member variables

Tags: c++, class, constructor, hashtable

So I am trying to implement a hash table and I am having trouble seeing what is wrong in my class or constructor. In summary when I try to reach an element of hash table array, I can in constructor, but I cannot in the member function (I get seg fault), which leads me to believe there is something wrong with my class/ constructor doesn't work.

```
website::website(int input) //Constructor
{       
    SIZE = input;

    node** hashtable = new node * [SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {       
            hashtable[i] = NULL;
            if(!hashtable[i])
            {       
                    cout<<"It works at "<<i<<"th"<<endl;//This is to check
            }
    }
}

int website::hashfunction(const char  array []) //Hash function
{

    int inputsize = strlen(array);
    int value = 0;

    for (int i=0; i< inputsize; i++)
    {       
            value = value + int(array[i]);
    }

    value = value % SIZE;

    return value;
 }
```

These functions do what they are supposed to do

but when I run this function. I get seg fault at `hashtable[place]==NULL` level.

```
int website::insert(const mainentry& input)
{
    int place = 0;

    node*temp = new node;
     /* Ignore this part
    temp->data.topic = new char[strlen(input.topic)+1];
    strcpy(temp->data.topic, input.topic);

    temp->data.url = new char[strlen(input.url)+1];
    strcpy(temp->data.url, input.url);

    temp->data.summary = new char[strlen(input.summary)+1];
    strcpy(temp->data.summary, input.summary);

    temp->data.review = new char[strlen(input.review)+1];
    strcpy(temp->data.review, input.review);

    temp->data.rating = input.rating;
    */

     place = hashfunction(temp->data.topic);
    cout<<"Place is: "<<place<<endl; //Hash function works correctly
    if (hashtable[place]== NULL) // THIS IS THE PART I GET SEG FAULT
    {
            hashtable[place] = temp;
            temp->next = NULL;
            return 1;
    }
    else
    {
            temp->next = hashtable[place];
            hashtable[place] = temp;
            return 1;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Here is my class:

```
class website
{
        public:
                website(int input);
//              ~website();
                int insert(const mainentry & input);
                int retrieve( char [], mainentry output [] );
                int edit (mainentry & input);
                int remove();
                int display(char []);
                int display_all();
                int hashfunction(const char []);

        private:

                int SIZE;
                node ** hashtable;
};
```

I am assuming I am making a beginner's mistake but I can't see what is going on, if anyone can direct me, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Use std::vector instead of new[]!

Comment: @manni66 unfortunately not allowed to use vectors or strings in this class :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`node** hashtable = new node * [SIZE];`

should be

`hashtable = new node * [SIZE];`

Answer (score 6):

You are shadowing the class's `hashtable` variable in the constructor by writing:

```
website::website(int input) //Constructor
{       
    SIZE = input;

    node** hashtable = new node * [SIZE]; //<<-- Shadowing. you are declaring a local scope veriable called hastable, and not using the class's instance.
}
```